# Ruby on Rails Getting Foreign Key to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I feel like this is a simple error that I can not figure out, but I haven't found anything online to help explain what I am doing incorrectly.  I have three tables created in my Ruby on Rails application:

```
Facility
 facility_name - string
 address       - string
 city_id       - integer
 state_id      - integer
 
 and foreign keys: cities, states

City
  city_name    - integer
  state_id     - integer

State
  state_short  - string
  state_long   - string
```

and I have the models defined as:

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :city
  has_one :state
end


class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :facility
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :facility
end
```

I thought I would be able to bring up the city and state within the facility by the following code on the rails console:

```
x = Facility.first
x.city_name
x.state_long
```

but both of those codes give an error.  Am I mistaking that by having the `city_id` and the `state_id` in the facilities table and the relationships as above, I should be able to get the `city_name` and `state_long` from the respective tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :city
  has_one :state
end
```

It means `cities` and `states` tables have `facility_id` column

But in your schema `facilties` have `city_id` and `state_id`

It means you need change your associations this way

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :state
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  has_one :facility
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
  has_one :facility
end
```

Another option is to change schema (if keep associations)

```
facilities
-----------
facility_name
address

cities
-----------
city_name
state_id 
facility_id

states
-----------
state_short
state_long
facility_id
```

Other words you [need choose](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) between `belongs_to` and `has_one`

> The distinction is in where you place the foreign key (it goes on the table for the class declaring the `belongs_to` association), but you should give some thought to the actual meaning of the data as well. The `has_one` relationship says that one of something is yours - that is, that something points back to you

In any case if instance of facility hasn't `city_name` and `state_long` methods error will occurred because adding associations doesn't define methods of associated model(s)

You can call it like this

```
facility = Facility.first
facility.city.city_name
facility.state.state_long
```

But can add such methods

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :state

  def city_name
    city.city_name
  end

  def state_long
    state.state_long
  end
end
```

or using `delegate` method

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :state

  delegate :city_name, to: :city
  delegate :state_long, to: :state
end
```

After that you can call it like this

```
facility = Facility.first
facility.city_name
facility.state_long
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I misunderstood how belongs_to works, but switching them around fixed the problem! Thank you for the additional explanation of where it goes in relation to the foreign key.  That makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `city_name` from the `city` relation in the `facility` model like so:

```
x = Facility.first
x.city.city_name
```

same for the `state_long`

```
x.state.state_long
```